# Text to Caesar Cipher

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and i made a code in C++ to convert 3 characters to caesar cipher but my problem is that i can print only characters to a - w. How can i print x, y ,z using only if else statement. I have tried else if and many other things but it prints for x,y,z {|} which is +3 i know i need to do -23 but i cant get it to work pls help. This is my code for only to a - w. Edit : i still don’t get how to go from x,y,z to a,b,c if some1 has an code example i would appreciate it cus im trying but it for some reason keeps printing {|} which is ch = ch + 3; and not ch = ch - 23; which is the one i want to do with else if statement

```
      char ch1;
char ch2;
char ch3;

cout << "Insert three characters: " << endl;
cin >> ch1;
cin >> ch2;
cin >> ch3;
if (ch1 >= '97' && ch1 <= '119' || ch2 <= '97' && ch2 <= '119' || ch3 >= '97' && ch3 <= '119') {
    ch1 = ch1 + 3;
    ch2 = ch2 + 3;
    ch3 = ch3 + 3;
cout << "Caesar Cipher: " << ch1 << ch2 << ch3 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `'97'` is not correct. It's a multi-byte character, which is going to lead to a bad time. Just use `'a'`. Have you learned about the modulo operator, `%`?

Comment: Yeah i have actually. Do i need to use % ?

Comment: I'm not going to say "obviously," but would I have asked you about a random operator just for fun?

Comment: Okay sorry i will try to fix it now thank you very much!

Comment: The same logic needs to be applied to each character individually. To avoid repetition create a function `char Encrypt(char c) { ... }` and deal with a single character at a time (`std::cout << "Caesar Cipher: " << Encrypt(ch1) << Encrypt(ch2) << Encrypt(ch3) << '\n';`) Also you don't want to hardcode char codes; this makes the code much harder to read; use `'a'`, not `97`.

Comment: Also worth noting that it will be a lot easier to ensure you stick with one of lower-case or upper-case letters.

Comment: Note: When you have sequentially named or numbered variables, odds are very good that your code would be easier to write and understand with an array or container..

Comment: in this case it may be simpler to directly check and -26 (instead of `%`). as letters are not 0-based coded.

Comment: Avoid magic numbers. 97 is harder to interpret than 'a' and on some systems 'a' won't be 97. You also can't be certain that the letters will be encoded in a nice contiguous  ascending block. Use the ctype functions like `isalpha` to avoid an unexpected butt-kicking.

Comment: `97` (no quotes) is the ASCII value for `'a'` (a literal character in single quotes). Don't use *MagicNumbers* like `97`. Always use the literal, e.g. `'a'` and `'z'`, etc.. They are equivalent, but the literals are much easier to read and convey what you are attempting to do. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap your characters around, you need the modulo operator, `%`. But first you must transform the letter to a zero-based value. After that, you have a number in the range [0, 25] and you can offset it. You then take the modulo to wrap the new value to the same range and finally transform it back to an alphabet character.

Example:

```
ch1 = 'a' + (ch1 - 'a' + 3) % 26;
```

Notice I'm using a character literal here. You should always avoid hard-coding character values, as that just makes your code more difficult to read and less portable. To test if a value is lowercase, there's a standard library function `std::islower` (and a corresponding `std::isupper`) found in the header `<cctype>`.

Fixing your code up a bit, it becomes:

```
if (std::islower(ch1)) ch1 = 'a' + (ch1 - 'a' + 3) % 26;
if (std::islower(ch2)) ch2 = 'a' + (ch2 - 'a' + 3) % 26;
if (std::islower(ch3)) ch3 = 'a' + (ch3 - 'a' + 3) % 26;
cout << "Caesar Cipher: " << ch1 << ch2 << ch3 << endl;
```

But look at all the code duplication! What if you want to change the key, or use more or less characters, or change the encoding algorithm completely? That's where a function comes in handy:

```
char EncodeChar(char c, int key)
{
   if (std::islower(c))
      c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + key) % 26;
   return c;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
const int key = 3;
ch1 = EncodeChar(ch1, key);
ch2 = EncodeChar(ch2, key);
ch3 = EncodeChar(ch3, key);
```

Even better, read your characters into a `std::string` and encode it in-place. You're no longer restricted to exactly three characters:

```
void CaesarEncode(std::string& s, int key)
{
    for (char& c : s) c = EncodeChar(c, key);
}
```

Call that like this:

```
std::string text = "Hello, world!";
CaesarEncode(text, 3);
std::cout << text << "\n";
```

Now, this will work for positive offsets, but not negatives. If you need to apply a negative offset, you need to add an additional 26 before modulo which ensures you never go below zero. It's useful to support both, because you probably want to *decode* the ciphertext at some point. You can use the same function but make the key negative.

One way to approach this is to modify a negative key at the last minute with a recursive call in your `CaesarEncode` function:

```
void CaesarEncode(std::string& s, int key)
{
    if (key < 0)
    {
        CaesarEncode(s, 26 - (-key % 26));
        return;
    }
    for (char& c : s) c = CaesarEncode(c, key);
}
```

Let's continue. What about capital letters? You can handle those too:

```
char EncodeChar(char c, int key)
{
    if (std::isalpha(c))
    {
        char base = std::islower(c) ? 'a' : 'A';
        c = base + (c - base + key) % 26;
    }
    return c;
}
```

As you can see, using functions makes life much easier, because you don't need to create a mess when beefing up your encoding method. You just change the core logic in one place.

---

Rolling this all together, and with a few extra helpers from the standard library, you get a reasonably compact program that can encode and decode:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

std::string CaesarEncode(const std::string& s, int key)
{
    if (key < 0)
    {
        return CaesarEncode(s, 26 - (-key % 26));
    }
    
    auto fnEncodeChar = [key](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char
    {
        if (std::isalpha(c))
        {
            char base = std::islower(c) ? 'a' : 'A';
            c = base + (c - base + key) % 26;
        }
        return c;
    };

    std::string encoded;
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(encoded), fnEncodeChar);
    return encoded;
}

std::string CaesarDecode(const std::string& s, int key)
{
    return CaesarEncode(s, -key);
}

int main()
{
    const int KEY = 3;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::string encoded = CaesarEncode(line, KEY);
        std::string decoded = CaesarDecode(encoded, KEY);
        std::cout << "Original : " << line << "\n";
        std::cout << "Encoded  : " << encoded << "\n";
        std::cout << "Decoded  : " << decoded << "\n";
    }
}
```

Input:

```
This is a test.
```

Output:

```
Original : This is a test.
Encoded  : Wklv lv d whvw.
Decoded  : This is a test.
```